how to get emacsclient to behave like emacs?
I don't like that emacsclient keeps buffers open. Is there a way so when I C-x C-c out of a session, it behaves like a regular emacs instance and kills all associated buffers? It'd also be nice if they could avoid sharing buffers, but as long as all the buffers are killed when none are open, I am happy.
I tried C-x # but it isn't great. Looking for a solution that enables me to C-x C-c the same as with regular emacs.

I must be confused. What is the point of using an Emacs server if it kills all your buffers when you disconnect?

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

"I tried C-x # but it isn't great." The question is unclear. Please explain what you want to know, in particular wrt what C-x # does.

Have you consulted (emacs) Exiting and (elisp) Killing Emacs? In particular, hooks kill-emacs-hook and kill-emacs-query-functions?

Faster start-up @db48x. My goal is to get it to function just like regular emacs, since that's cleaner for my use case.

I tried a solution with kill-emacs-hook and kill-emacs-query-functions but it seems like it doesn't work (for example, when you say no to saving) for killing all my buffers @Drew

Faster startup can be had just by removing most uses of require from your init file.

I don't have any uses of require @db48x. I use use-package.

Make sure you are allowing use-package to defer loading the package, otherwise it is just calling require for you.

Ok. I'll try that @db48x. Is there any cases where I must :ensure it?

The manual is pretty clear on that; I wouldn't want to just repeat it.

Can you point me in the page? @db48x

Perhaps you should look at the section entitled “When to use :defer”. Or you should ask it as an actual question. Although very probably others have asked before you, and gotten answers. You might seek out these earlier questions first so as to avoid creating a duplicate, as duplicates are rarely as useful to future visitors as completely new questions.

Isn't that a different question than when to :ensure t? That was my question and I don't see any definitive answers.

@user129393192 :ensure t allows to automatically install a package if it wasn't found. Whether to use it is up to you, but I personally prefer not to set it, and then if I'm at situation where I migrate to a new system without any packages I set use-package-always-ensure to t explicitly for the duration of me needing to have packages installed.

@user129393192 btw, regarding your confusion about :defer — I just realized there is a use-package-always-defer that one can set to t. In my .emacs (I just counted) 61% of uses of use-package have defer t. I suppose one may set use-package-always-defer to t, and instead explicitly "undefer" the packages a user wants to have immediately available (which are on the lesser side).

For the original question: it is possible but requires some coding. You may not know, but Emacs already does kill all buffers associated with emacsclient (in the server-delete-client function). You can get the list of them with (process-get (nth 0 server-clients) 'buffers). The problem is that Emacs does not add into that list any buffers besides those passed to emacsclient on the command line initially. You'd have to do that manually with (process-put … 'buffers …) in a buffer creation hook. The only problem is, Idk how to distinguish if it's created from a client or original Emacs.

Although, after some experimenting I'm not so sure it works like that… Either way, this is something for you to research  emacsclient definitely does kill some associated buffers, because if you quit it the buffer for the file that was passed on command line goes down as well. If I was you I'd research the process property list that I mentioned above. But start with the question of how to distinguish the current instance from all others.
